# What is the term for starting an essay with a story or anecdote to pique the reader's attention?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am looking for the formal academic term for this - not "opener" or "opening."  I want to refer to it in a presentation about creating hooks to pull in the reader.  I once knew the term but cannot now remember or find it.

Comment: ... I don't have an answer, but since this *is* an English usage website, I thought I'd point out that "pique" is the word you want in your title instead of "peak".

Comment: You used the word _peak_ in your title, which is a common mistake: you wanted to use _pique_, which is the term that actually means "to arouse the interest of."

Comment: @Gilead ...jynx.

Answer (score 1):

[Hook](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hook).

Comment: Oh. Wait. I just realized that you (OP) already know that word (as you used it in your question). Nonetheless, AFAIK, that's the word for it.

Comment: Seeing as he used the word in his question, I don't think that's the word he's looking for.

Comment: I can't think of a term specifically for starting with a story/anecdote.  Hook would be your best bet

Comment: "Opening" or "anecdote" are all I can dig up. Just ran through a list of the classic Greek rhetorical devices and this ain't one of 'em.

Answer (score 1):

Such an introduction is known as *arrestive* in some grammar circles.